# Conversion of files to Mapsforge *.map format

Tags: convert, file-formats, mapping, mapsforge

I am a complete newbie and not a cartographer. I organize off-road events such as 4X4 trail rides, biking events and running events.  Many of these trails/event maps have been created in different file types. To track trail leaders and participants I am currently using APSdroid This software uses the Mapsforge *.map file format.

What are my options and what file formats can be converted to the *.map file format?

Comment: Sorry I am not smart enough to ask the question any better. My last sentence is all I wanted to know

Answer (score 3):

I would refer you to this website, [Mapsforge Map-Writer](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Map-Writer.md)

> The Mapsforge Map-Writer is a plug-in for the OpenStreetMap Osmosis Tool to convert OSM data files into maps that can be displayed with mapsforge.

There are few options that may be available, however this is the most common approach that I've found for what you are looking for.